# Ошибка в консоли

Tags: javascript

При загрузке страницы появляется ошибка в консоли

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

ругается на строку

```
var join = $('.wallets-deposit__inner'),
```

Comment: `jquery` забыли подключить?

Comment: Или `jquery` должен подключаться _раньше_, чем скрипт с ошибкой